# How to set the alignment in a platform independent way?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-alignment

In the [latest draft of the c++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf), chapter 3.11 talks about the alignment.
Later, the chapter 7.6.1 defines how to define an aligned structures (or variables?)

If I define a structure like this :

```
alignas(16) struct A
{
  int n;
  unsigned char[ 1020 ];
};
```

does it means that all instances of the class A are going to be aligned to 16 bytes?

Or, do I have to do it like in the next code?

```
struct A
{
  char data[300];
};
alignas(16) A a;
```

If both examples are wrong, how to do it properly?

PS I am not looking for a compiler dependent solution.

Comment: FYI, n3242 is not the latest draft. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alignment is first and foremost a property of types.

It can be overridden for a type with `alignas`; `alignas` can *also* be used to assign a new alignment value to a specific object.

So, both examples are valid, and will have the semantics that you've presumed.

> `[n3290: 3.11/1]:` Object types have *alignment requirements* (3.9.1,
>   3.9.2) which place restrictions on the addresses at which an object of
>   that type may be allocated. An *alignment* is an implementation-defined
>   integer value representing the number of bytes between successive
>   addresses at which a given object can be allocated. **An object type
>   imposes an alignment requirement on every object of that type;**
>   stricter alignment can be requested using the alignment specifier
>   (7.6.2).
>
> `[n3290: 7.6.2/1]:` **An *alignment-specifier* may be applied to a
>   variable or to a class data member**, but it shall not be applied to a
>   bit-field, a function parameter, the formal parameter of a catch
>   clause (15.3), or a variable declared with the `register` storage class
>   specifier. **An *alignment-specifier* may also be applied to the
>   declaration of a class or enumeration type.** An *alignment-specifier*
>   with an ellipsis is a pack expansion (14.5.3).
>
> `[n3290: 7.6.2/2]:` When the alignment-specifier is of the form
>   `alignas( assignment-expression ):`
>
> - the assignment-expression shall be an integral constant expression
> - if the constant expression evaluates
>     to a fundamental alignment, the alignment requirement of the declared
>     entity shall be the specified fundamental alignment
> - if the constant
>     expression evaluates to an extended alignment and the implementation
>     supports that alignment in the context of the declaration, the
>     alignment of the declared entity shall be that alignment
> - if the
>     constant expression evaluates to an extended alignment and the
>     implementation does not support that alignment in the context of the
>     declaration, the program is ill-formed
> - if the constant expression
>     evaluates to zero, the alignment specifier shall have no effect
> - otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: Can you add an example please?

Comment: @VJo: Huh? There are two examples in your question. This question is about validating the first example, isn't it?

Comment: Right! I failed to munch so much text at once.